# ¿Cómo emplear una variable generada de un bucle en otro bucle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un pequeño problema con el siguiente código en *Python*, de un ciclo tipo `for`, genero la variable `Pc`. Esta variable contiene varios datos enteros (ejemplo: `0, 1, 2, 3`). Luego, al momento de utilizar dicha variable en otro ciclo `for` no me trabaja con todos los valores, sino únicamente con el último valor, por ejemplo, `3`.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de mantener los mismos valores del primer ciclo `for` en el segundo.

```
pro = int(input("Ingrese profundidad de pozo: "))
od = float(input("Ingrese el diametro externo: "))
id = float(input("Ingrese el diametro interno: "))
Yp = int(input("Ingrese cedencia: "))
ptub = float(input("Ingrese densidad de fluido: "))
panu = float(input("Ingrese densidad de fluido anular: "))


data = np.loadtxt("practica.txt", delimiter=',', skiprows=0)

k=(len(data))
j=int(pro/k)

area=((od**2)-(id**2))*0.7854
t = ((od - id) / 2)
s= (od/t)

for ca in data:
    ca1 = (ca / area)    
    BB = (ca1 / Yp)
    cc = ((1 - (0.75 * ((BB) ** (2)))))
    if cc<0:
        cc = 0
    d = (((cc) **(0.5)) - (0.5 * BB))
    d1 = (((cc) **(0.5)) + (0.5 * BB))


    Ype= d * Yp
    Ype1=d1 * Yp


    a = 2.8762 + (0.10679* (0.00001)*Ype )+(0.21301 * (0.0000000001) * ((Ype) ** (2)))- (0.53132 * (1E-16) * ((Ype) **(3)))

    b = 0.026233 + (0.50609 * (0.000001) * Ype)
    c = -465.93 + (0.030867 * Ype) - (0.10483 * (0.0000001) * ((Ype) ** (2))) + (0.36989 * (0.0000000000001) * ((Ype) ** (3)))
    O = (b / a)
    f = ((46.95 * 1000000) * (((3 * O) / (2 + O)) ** (3))) / ((Ype * (((3 * O) / (2 + O) - O))) * ((1 - ((3 * O) / (2 + O)))) ** (2))

    g = f * O

    L = (c/ Ype)
    s1 = ((((a - 2) + (8 * (b+ L))) ** (0.5)) + (a - 2)) / (2 * (b + L))
    s1=abs(s1)
    s2 = (Ype * (a - f)) / (c + (Ype * (b - g)))
    s2=float(s2)
    s3 = (2 + (b / a)) / (3 * b / a)
    s3=float(s3)



    Pc1 =((-2 * Ype * ((s - 1) / (s * s))))
    Pc2 = ((((Ype * ((a / s) - b)) - c)*-1)) 
    Pc3 = (-(Ype * ((f / s) - g)))
    Pc4 = (-(46.95 * 1000000) / (s * ((s - 1) ** 2)))


    Pc0=0  
    Pc0=int(Pc0)   


    if s<s1 : 
        Pc=(Pc1)

    elif s1<s<s2:
                    Pc=(Pc2)

    elif s2 < s < s3:
                Pc=(Pc3)

    elif s>s3:
                Pc=(Pc4)
    print(Pc)

DFB=[] 
DFC=[]   

for h in list(range(0,pro+1,j)):
    K=list(range(0,pro+1,j))


    Ptu=(round(0.052*h*ptub))+2000
    Pan=round(0.052*h*panu)
    delta_p=abs(Ptu-Pan)
    Pequi=Pan-(1-(2/s))*Ptu

    Pb = (0.875 * 2 * Yp * t) / od 
    print(Pequi)
    DFB.append(Pb/delta_p)
    DFC.append((Pc/Pequi))
```

Comment: Con respecto a esto... _cuestiones de espacio solo pego el segundo ciclo_, yo te recomendaría ponerlo igual. No existen problemas de espacio.

Comment: Añade los dos ciclos completos como te recomienda ArtEze, para que podamos ver la lógíca (solo veo un `for` y no usa `Pc`). Ten en cuenta que debes aportar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Si `Pc` toma un valor distinto en cada iteración del primer ciclo y quieres usar ese valor en el segundo debes colocar el segundo dentro del primer ciclo o guardar cada valor generado en una lista u otra estructura. Lógicamente si usas una variable dentro de un ciclo `for` su valor trás ejecutar el ciclo va a ser el que se le asigne en la última iteración.